# React.js - Pattern for handling dumb children state?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to keep my components pure (the state lives outside the component that is changing) - by passing in the state from the parent.

I have three links that I want to change to active, but instead of affecting all of them I would just like to affect the one that was clicked / active.

Some questions left unanswered: Where should the logic sit for filtering out which element was clicked? How do we do this by keeping the children dumb?

here is what I got so far:

jsFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/33470/

```
var SomeElement = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return(
      <a className={this.props.className} onClick={this.props.onClick} href="#">Click Me!</a>
    )
  }
});

var App = React.createClass({  
  click: function(e) {
    this.setState({class: "active"})
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return({class: ""})
  },
  render: function() {
    return(
      <div>
        <SomeElement className={this.state.class} onClick={this.click} />
        <SomeElement className={this.state.class} onClick={this.click} />
        <SomeElement className={this.state.class} onClick={this.click} />
      </div>
    )
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the name of the class which is used when an element is active should be internal to the element. Parent component should not know about that:

```
var SomeElement = React.createClass({
  className: function() {
    return this.props.active ? "active" : "";
  },
  render: function() {
    return (        
      <a className={this.className()} onClick={this.props.onClick} href="#">Click Me!</a>
    )
  }
});

<SomeElement active={true,false} onClick={this.click} />
```

---

The next point depends on how you want to represent the state of your application. I'll give two examples:

```
state: {
  element1Active: false,
  element2Active: false,
  element3Active: false,
}

click: function(elementNumber) {
  var stateUpdate = {}, key = 'element' + elementNumber + 'Active';
  stateUpdate[key] = !this.state[key];
  this.setState(stateUpdate);
}

<SomeElement active={this.state.element1Active} onClick={this.click} />
```

or (probably better)

```
state: {
  activeElementIndex: 0,
}

click: function(elementIndex) {
  this.setState({activeElementIndex: elementIndex});
}

<SomeElement active={this.state.activeElementIndex === 0} onClick={this.click} />
```

---

And finally, to filter which button is clicked, you can bind arguments to the callback:

```
return(
  <SomeElement active={this.state.activeElementIndex === 0} onClick={this.click.bind(this, 0)} />
  <SomeElement active={this.state.activeElementIndex === 1} onClick={this.click.bind(this, 1)} />
  <SomeElement active={this.state.activeElementIndex === 2} onClick={this.click.bind(this, 2)} />
)
```

Comment: Looks good, I like your solution - Just wanted to point out that the variable inside `SomeElement` is invalid code - since that is an object and not a function it should be inside a function like so: 
 ```className: function() {
   return this.props.active ? "active" : "not-active";
  },``` and used as `this.className()`